# Struts2 action without result

Tags: struts2, actionresult

I am coding a simple shoping cart, but I don´t know how to do this:

This is a part of the jsp:

```
<s:iterator value="#session.listaLibros" var="libro">
                <tr>
                    <td><s:property  value="titulo"/></td>
                    <td><s:property value="autor"/></td>
                    <td><s:property value="precio"/></td>
                    <s:hidden name="isbn" value="%{idLibro}"/>
                    <td><s:url var="url" action="comprar">
                            <s:param name="idLibro" value="isbn"/>
                        </s:url>
                        <s:a href="%{url}">Comprar</s:a></td>
                </tr>
            </s:iterator>
```

It has a table in which you can see book details. In each row, there is a link to buy the book. I have coded it with  and , and I pass the parameter with  inside the .

THe problem is that I don´t want to go to another jsp page. When you click the link, it triggers an action (add the book to a list) and show the list on another table at the bottom of the same jsp page.
How can I do it?

If I write a new action without a result on the xml file, I get error.
I have written a new class that doesn´t extend ActionSupport, but also doesn´t work. I get a blank page.

```
//ActionClass
public class Comprar {
.
.
//Action method
public void comprarLibro(){
....
}
```

struts.xml

```
<!--Action for the ActionSupport action class-->

<action name="comprarLibroAction" class="controller.ComprarLibroAction"  method="comprarLibro">

    </action>

    <!--Simple action class-->
    <action name="comprar" class="controller.Comprar" method="comprarLibro"></action>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax is the solution. Here is an explanation of how to create the front end part and the back end part. The front-end part is very simple... It just adds the element to the cart, no ajax call is inserted and the quantity is not considered.

**Front end**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.buy').click(function() {
    // retrieve book description
    var bookId = $(this).attr('id');
    var description = $(this).parent().parent().find('.description').html();
    
    // HERE ADD THE AJAX CALL
    // On success function use this code to add values to the cart
    var tr = $('<tr />');
    var td = $('<td />', {id: bookId, html: description});
    
    $(tr).append(td);
    
    $('#cart tbody').append(tr);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td class="description">Asd Asd by Asd</td>
      <td><button id="1" class="buy">Buy!</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td class="description">Lol by Lol</td>
      <td><button type="button" id="2" class="buy">Buy!</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class="description">Struts by Apache</td>
      <td><button type="button" id="3" class="buy">Buy!</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="cart">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Cart</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Back end**

For the backend part you have to use the Struts2 JSON plugin in order to setup an action that can be called by Ajax and returns the desired JSON result (for example if the book is still available, or updates the session cart... For more information have a look at the [official documentation](https://struts.apache.org/docs/json-plugin.html) and google for some examples...

here is an example:

**struts.xml**

```
<struts>
    <package name="example"  extends="json-default">
        <action name="JSONExample" class="example.JSONExample">
            <result type="json"/>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

The CartAction on **SUCCESS** will automatically map all your action attributes (the ones with getter and setters) into a JSON object that can be elaborated inside the **success** ajax function

```
// Ajax call
success: function(response) {
    // ...
    var tr = $('<tr />');
    var td = $('<td />', {id: bookId, html: description});
}
```

Comment: Thnak you very much, @IIGala , but I´m trying to do it without javascript. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: The only one is to refresh the same page on action success.... But can be very expensive.... Everything l the user buys has to refresh the page? JQuery it's a much better solution